# Higlight opened dropdown menu on bootstrap 5 navbar

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Bootstrap 5 navbar is used to create dropdown menu.

How to hightlight current menu item above opened dropdown like is windows desktop application so that user can see menu item where opened dropdown belongs.

Bootstrap 5 does not provide any highlight:

[image]

How to make Dropdown2 background lighter or darker or provide other indication if its drowndown is opened ?

Navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown1
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>A</u>ction</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A<u>n</u>other action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>S</u>omething else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown2
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>A</u>ction</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A<u>n</u>other action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>S</u>omething else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown3
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>A</u>ction</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A<u>n</u>other action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><u>S</u>omething else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Testcase is in https://www.codeply.com/p/2U6C3qPw2x

Bootstrap 5, ASP.NET 6 MVC are used. Latest Jquery is also installed.

Comment: When I try the codeply I'm seeing the highlight. The chrome dev tools Styles tab says it applies the .dropdown-item:focus and .dropdown-item:hover styles. The color is super pale #e9ecef;

Comment: The hover styles should already be applied.. I see them when I test the code

Comment: @ourmandave I tried in latest chrome but dropdown caption is not highlighted if dropdown is opened as shown in image in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicked on dropdown is adding a `.show` class automaticaly, you can use this selector and define a style:

```css
.nav-link.dropdown-toggle.show{
    background:orange;
}
```

[show result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz6k9.png)